# Speed up finding next index in another list of indices (numpy)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, cython, numba

The code below works as desired but it does not seem optimized because of the loop. I have been able to successfully vectorize all of my other methods but I cannot seem to figure out how to remove the loop on this one.

Speedwise: It becomes an issue when I have millions of rows.

Is there a way to vectorize this or should I try out cython or numba? I have been trying to limit the number of packages used.

Sample code:

```
import numpy as np

leading = np.array([814, 935, 1057, 3069])

within = np.array([193, 207, 243, 251, 273, 286, 405, 427, 696, 770, 883,
                   896, 1004, 2014, 2032, 2033, 2046, 2066, 2079, 2154])

# find first following elements in within array
first_after_leading = []
for _ in leading:
    temp = (within - _).max()

    first_after_leading.append(temp)

# convert to np array
first_after_leading = np.array(first_after_leading)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max of subtraction from each element in `leading` against all elements in `within` will be subtraction of `leading` from max of `within`. Hence, simply do -

```
within.max() - leading
```

No extra modules required.

Timings -

```
In [79]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: within = np.random.rand(1000000)
    ...: leading = np.random.rand(400000)

In [80]: %timeit within.max() - leading
1000 loops, best of 3: 850 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  This is very helpful with no extra modules

Comment: At least on my machine, when I use your test arrays that are floats, your method is 2.2x faster than my `find_leading_nb2` function. But with the same sizes, but `leading` and `within` as integer arrays, my function is 2x faster than your on-liner.

Comment: @JoshAdel My one-liner as in `within.max() - leading`?

Comment: yes. I think we both realized what the algorithm was actually doing at about the same time after our initial responses, thus my updated function, and you replacing the original broadcasting.

Comment: @JoshAdel Well I posted both broadcasting and this one-liner. Of course, I realized that the broadcasting one won't be efficient or elegant. So, I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

With numba you can make a fairly simple translation of your code:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def find_leading(leading, within):
    # find first following elements in within array
    first_after_leading = []
    for _ in leading:
        temp = (within - _).max()

        first_after_leading.append(temp)

    # convert to np array
    first_after_leading = np.array(first_after_leading)

    return first_after_leading


@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def find_leading_nb(leading, within):
    # find first following elements in within array
    first_after_leading = np.empty_like(leading)
    for i, _ in enumerate(leading):
        temp = (within - _).max()

        first_after_leading[i] = temp

    return first_after_leading
```

And then with your original input:

```
%timeit find_leading(leading, within)
%timeit find_leading_nb(leading, within)
%timeit (within[:,None] - leading).max(0)
17.3 µs ± 169 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
1.7 µs ± 25.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
6.48 µs ± 180 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

and then with some larger arrays:

```
leading = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000,))
within = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100000,))

%timeit find_leading(leading, within)
%timeit find_leading_nb(leading, within)
%timeit (within[:,None] - leading).max(0)
145 ms ± 3.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
67.4 ms ± 218 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
553 ms ± 4.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Timings run with numba 0.44 and numpy 1.16.4 on MacOS python 3.7

**EDIT**

But if I"m understanding your algorithm correctly, a much faster approach is to only find the max of `within` once and then take the difference with `leading`, so you don't have to find the `max` of a temporary array in the loop:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def find_leading_nb2(leading, within):
    max_within = within.max()
    first_after_leading = np.empty_like(leading)
    for i, x in enumerate(leading):
        first_after_leading[i] = max_within - x
    return first_after_leading
```

Which yields the following on your original inputs:

```
%timeit find_leading_nb2(leading, within)
919 ns ± 8.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

and the following on the large inputs:

```
%timeit find_leading_nb2(leading, within)
21.6 µs ± 180 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: If you're going to use `numba`, might as well just wrap `within.max() - leading` from Divakar's answer, it's about 3x faster than what you have now and easily supported by numba's capabilities

Comment: This is a great write up and additional timings. Definitely shows the difference between the methods. When you use numba and timeit how does the jit compile time play into that? it is averaged correct?

Comment: @user3483203 - just wrapping Divakar's solution in numba is actually no faster than `find_leading_nb2`, which makes me think that the numba implementation of `.max()` is different and sub-optimal

Comment: Can you post how the timings with integer is better on numba? Is it really that even a simple operation like subtracting a scalar from an array is faster on numba than on NumPy?

Comment: @JoshAdel I was commenting about your slower solution with the unnecessary calculations.  Your last solution and Divakar's generate basically identical bytecode using numba.

Answer (score 0):

I guess making it single liner would help. Try it.

```
first_after_leading =np.array([(within - _).max() for _ in leading])
```